# retrieve ajax data and return it to synchronous code to create an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I have a question concerning ajax once again, and I have looked through some questions on here [this one in particular(how to pass back an object from an ajax success handler to the calling function?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810094/how-to-pass-back-an-object-from-an-ajax-success-handler-to-the-calling-function), how do you grab data via ajax to populate an object? Last time I was asking specifically about the Facebook API, but that got me to think there has go to be a better way of doing it.

I thought you could perhaps create a listener to tell you when a certain ajax/api call has finished so you can then go back to the synchronous code and populate your object with that data. Any thoughts?

I really don't like being constricted to running my code within that async call as it ruins all of my nicely organized OOP code.

Any input is appreciated :)

Comment: If you make an async AJAX call, the response won't be processed while synchronous code is running. The only way to process the AJAX response in synchronous code is with a synchronous XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: This is considered the canonical question regarding returning from AJAX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Thanks ill check out he other question.